# evaluating speedup of sum of products

Tags: performance, parallel-processing, processor

Assuming that computing times of each elementary operation and interprocess communication times are the same, evaluate speedup  and efficiency of a full mesh processor network in the following cases:

a)Sum of products of 800 elements in a network of 4 processors;

b)Sum of products of 800 elements in a network of 8 processors;

c)Sum of products of 8000 elements in a network of 4 processors;

d)Sum of products of 8000 elements in a network of 8 processors;

How can I do this? I'm having troubles evaluating parallel computation times. For the sequential computation times I calculated them by adding the number of total sums and the number of total products (i.e in the first case I computed it as 799 t+800 t). Is this correct?

Comment: It's bad form to copy-paste homework questions to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, even if it wasn't, this question sounds like quackery so you'd be unlikely to get any helpful answers anyway.

Comment: That's an exercize of an exam test... Any hint is appreciated, I'm not looking for an easy answer man... However it's easy to say something is quackery  when you can't answer..